# Web scraping to find live view in you tube

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have written below codes to find out live view count from a youtube channel but it return none as output.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEgv0arvI1o")

data = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

livewatching=data.find("span", {"class" : "view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer"})

print (livewatching)
```

Comment: There is a YouTube API, use it that instead,

Comment: Can't We scrape without using API...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to automate the process of opening a browser and find the element you're looking for. (Don't forget to allow remote automation on your browser)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver=webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEgv0arvI1o")
streamcount = "//*[@id='count']/yt-view-count-renderer/span[1]"
streamcountelement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(streamcount))
print(streamcountelement.text)
```

Comment: Thanks ...it mean that this code automatically runs for every 10 secs right?

Comment: No, this waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 10 seconds.

Comment: @Sonu Don't forget to upvote if this helped you please